# how to access winform components from another class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, class

i have a form with one button and two labels

and i have a separate class called myCounter

i want the myCounter class to be able to access the labels in the form 
through a method called changeColor..

how can make the labels available in this class

the form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Color colTurn
        {
            get { return lblp1Turn.BackColor; }
            set { lblp1Turn.BackColor = value; }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

the class

```
class myCounter
{
    private readonly Form1 Board;
    public myCounter(Form1 Board)
    {
        this.Board = Board;
    }

    public int turn = 0;


    public void changeColor()
    {

        if (turn == 0)
        {
            turn = 1;
            lbl

           //change color code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried get and set

Comment: Could you show the code that you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried passing the items into your second class?

Comment: @Jon B what did u do to my question man

Comment: @Tacit: click on the "edited x minutes ago", then you'll see the revision history

Comment: whats the point in that he has just corrected my spelling

Comment: @Tacit: You state that you have tried with the "get and set", but did you actually set the value, as in `Board.colTurn = Color.Red` for instance?

Comment: @Tacit: What do you mean "what's the point"? The point is to correct spelling obviously. Jon B fixed the code you provided since it wasn't properly formatted, hence he added four spaces so it is correct.

Comment: @Tacit - I fixed a minor code formatting problem to make your question easier to read. Please don't take offense. This is part of how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it looks like you're passing the whole form into your second class anyway, So I'd do what LightStriker suggested. Make a public accessor for all of your items and then set it in your other class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private myCounter _counterClass;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Label MyLabel1
        {
            get {return mylabel1;}
        }

        public Label MyLabel2
        {
            get {return mylabel2;}
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _counterClass = new myCounter(this);
        }

        protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _counterClass.changeColor();
        }
    }
```

Then in your second class you have access to your Label.

```
class myCounter
{
    private readonly Form1 Board;
    public myCounter(Form1 Board)
    {
        this.Board = Board;
    }

    public int turn = 0;


    public void changeColor()
    {

        if (turn == 0)
        {
            turn = 1;
            Board.MyLabel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            Board.MyLabel2.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            turn = 0;
            Board.MyLabel2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            Board.MyLabel1.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this is code I have written in a wiki markup editor and is untested. This SHOULD work for you though.

Comment: Whatever property you're trying to change. You want to change BackColor right?

Comment: Can you tell me what's calling the changeColor method?

Comment: it will be a button in the form class.. do i need an instance of the myCounter class or how do i call this method

Comment: Ok then this code should work on the first button click assuming you're making and holding onto a myCounterClass in the formLoad. Does anything set `Turn` other than the changeColor method?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you tell me what you want the code to do in it's most basic form?

Comment: ok i have a form with 2 labels one button when i click the button it calls the change color method from the myCounter class and it will change the color of the labels if turn is 1 than label 2 will be yellow if turn is 0 then label 1 will be red the turn value will change from 0 to 1 then from 1 to 0 everytime the buttons is clicked

Comment: Do you ever set labels 1 or 2 back to white?

Comment: yes that will happen in the code where the colour changing is going on

Comment: Do you know the reason you can't access your Labels from the Form class is because they are protected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19097/discussion-between-ejc-and-tacit)

Comment: ther perfect answer just what i needed :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a public method on your form for this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
    public void SetLabelColor(Color color){
        mylabel.BackColor = color;
    }
    //... Other code
}
```

Comment: so how do i make the label available in the class

Comment: and why u using a partial class

Comment: @Tacit: It's just copied from *your* code. The partial class is because it's a form, and you're using a .designer.cs file in part with the code-behind cs file.

Comment: @Tacit: Also, "making label available" doesn't make any sense. You state that you want to expose the color of the label, which is just what Oscar provided here by using a method in the class.

Comment: i can do it with a method within a class but i wanted to do everything outside of the form class

Comment: @Tacit: Would you please specify what "it" and "everything" is in your last comment.