# Resize form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running two forms simultaneously and I am trying to resize `Form1` by calling a `Form1` method with an event in `Form2`. With the following code the proper size values are displayed in the console, but the size of `Form1` does not change. I have tried a number of approaches but I don't see why this does not work.

In Form1:

```
public void ResizeForm()
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.Size.ToString());
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(600, 300);
}
```

In Form2:

```
private void ResizeCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.ResizeForm();
}
```

Comment: Where are you acutally showing `form` also by the looks of your code how do you know which form is actually being resized since you are calling `Form1 form = new Form(1)` looking act your code one can't tell which came first the `Chicken or the Egg` if you're going to post code.. please show all relevant pieces also why can't you just do this 
`this.Size = new Size(600, 300);`

Comment: this.Size = new Size(600, 300); gives me the error 'Size' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Size' and 'System.Window.Size'. I understand "this" might be problematic in this scenario, which is why I am asking for an alternate approach. However, the console output indicates that I am referencing Form1.

Comment: this is not that difficult what I am basically saying is that you should take a different approach to what you are currently trying to do..

Comment: `System.Drawing.Size` is for GDI+ and `System.Window.Size` is for WPF. `Console` is another separate API which runs in a different process from your WinForm. It is very difficult to use three different graphics subsystems in the same project and you have probably done something seriously wrong. You need to post code that will show the problem to us.

Comment: Consult [How to access WinForm component from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233431/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the instance of the current `Form1` to the second form. Add an instance in `Form2` and then get it from `Form1`

Form2

```
Form1 _form1;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
 {
  InitializeComponent();
   _form1 = form1;
 }

private void ResizeCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1.ResizeForm();            
}
```

Then open `Form2` in the main form like this.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show((Form1)this); //I'm not sure if you need to cast "this" to From1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Form1 form = new Form1();` creates a new form, resizes it, and then forgets it. So, this is completely pointless.  The `ResizeForm()` method does get invoked, but on the wrong instance of `Form1`.  From your description, you should have some other instance of `Form1` somewhere, the instance that you are actually displaying to the user.  You need to access that instance from within `Form2`.  If you do not have access to the correct instance of `Form1` from within `Form2`, you must somehow pass it, so that `Form2` has it.  Creating a new instance of `Form1` is not going to resize the original instance of `Form1`.